# What is Data-navigate and data-position in html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<section id="attorneys" data-navigate="attorneys" data-position="-126">
    <div class="attorneys-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="clear clearfix"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                <div class="typography style2 webkit" data-animate="fadeInUp">
                    <i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <h3 class="text1">Meet here</h3>
                    <h1 class="text2">Our Attorneys</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

what is the use of the data elements in code , where are these linked and how works

Comment: It's nothing special. Generally, you use it in your `PHP` code to give `HTML` some data and get it with `JS` to do something with. Hope you understand

Comment: Somtimes you need to store some data in your HTML so that when some event triggers on your element, you could use that data. "data-attr" is a facility provided in HTML5 to store some data in your HTML tags

Answer (score 1):

Typically `data-` attributes are used to give extra meaning to elements and are commonly accessed via javascript.

The values can be retrieved via `getAttribute()` or `dataset` property on the element.

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or Node.setUserData().

See here for more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 1):

Data is attribute using to store custom data.
You can access it using jQuery as `$('div').data('key')` which return content of attribute `data-key` `<div data-key="xoxo">`.
Or set: `$('div').data('key', {'data':1})`.

Nice thing about data attribute is that it can keep original data format (other html attributes can't), so you can store object, arrays and don't need to parse them after read.

** keep in mind that if you update data from `js` content won't be visible from web console view.